# Form Buttons - datetime.now

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have trying to create a form button in Ruby on Rails that would simply drop the current date & time into the database for the specified field. EX: I have a button called "notified" and when the user clicks the button I want the notified field in the database to update to the date & time when the button was pressed. I am thinking I probably need to use some javascript with this however I am having a hard time to figure out where to start with this. Any advise?

Comment: Pls add some code.

Comment: I know this is not the proper code however I am trying to show what I mean... `Notified: <%= f.text_field :notified, value: 'time variable' %> <%= f.button 'Insert Time' %>`